# not able to login via tnsnames

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm running oracle 12c in rhel 6.6 in virtual box.

I've configured all the parameters for ODG and edited the tnsnames and listener files accordingly.

I am able to tnsping both the nodes but when I try to login via tnsnames, I get an ORA 12514

I have created orapwd file and copied it to the secondary node as well.

tnsnames

```
ODGORADBDR =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.35)(PORT = 1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = oradbdr)
    )
  )

ODGORADB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.30)(PORT = 1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = oradb)
    )
  )
```

Standby listener file

```
ORADBDR =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.35)(PORT = 1522))
    )

SID_LIST_ORADBR =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = oradbdr)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1)
      (ENVS='EPC_DISABLED=TRUE')
    )
  )
```

Primary db listener

```
ORADB =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.30)(PORT = 1522))
    )

SID_LIST_ORADB =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = oradb)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1)
      (ENVS='EPC_DISABLED=TRUE')
    )
  )
```

Just wanted to know if i'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: What are the service names of your DB - what does `lsnrctl services` show? Sounds like either your service names don't match your SIDs (which isn't unusual), or your DBs aren't running, or are running but can't register with the listener.

Comment: Hello Alex, from primary database i.e oradb it is able to show the service when I check the listener status. but for the secondary node it shows that there are no services associated with the listener.I took backup from primary and restored it in another node to configure ODG, the secondary node is in mounted state. The instance name from os level is oradbdr.